# Find array indices of values greater than given distance in O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array with indices 1 ... n and corresponding values x<sub>1</sub> ... x<sub>n</sub> and the values are sorted in increasing order, left *f(i)* be the first index (smaller than i) of the greatest value (from the right to the left) with |x<sub>i</sub> - x<sub>f(i)</sub>| > 5. For example given (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>) = (6, 7, 12, 14) then f(4) = 2 because the index of the greatest value (from the right to the left) with a distance greater than 5 is 7 (as 14-12 would only be a distance of 2), f(3) = 1 and f(2),f(1) are undefiened (no cycles/modulo because index f(i) must be smaller than i). 
I'm searching for an algorithm that finds f(n),f(n-1), ..., f(1) alltogether in time complexity O(n). 
The naive version has O(n<sup>2</sup>) only.

Comment: per your definition of `f(x)`, `f(1) = f(2) = 4`.

Comment: Are you sure that a O(n) solution even exists for this problem?

Comment: @Paul you are right, to be more specific it is the first index **smaller than i** with the greatest value from the right to the left with a distance greater of five

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observation that leads to O(n) time algorithm is that for i < j where both f(i) and f(j) are defined, f(i) <= f(j), i.e., f is an (non-strictly) increasing function. Therefore, when for an index i we find f(i), f(i-1) has to be either equal to or smaller than f(i).
Here is a piece of code that captures the essence of the algorithm.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  f[i] = -1; //initialize to undefined 
int j = n-1;
int i = n;
while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
  while ((j > 0) && (x[i] - x[j] <= 5))
    j--;
  if (x[i] - x[j] > 5)
    f[i] = j;
  i--;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! I'm not sure, but I'm afraid that your solution is based on my unprecise/uncomplete specification (I'm sorry!), that would allow a cycle/modulo for the indices. But as I commented above it should say "the first index smaller than i with the greatest value from the right to the left with a distance greater of five" (this implies f(i) < i).

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect change in problem definition. Note that using absolute value is not needed anymore.